# I had a plan vs I have a plan

Tags: grammar, verbs

Let's say you guys are setting up a plan to catch a burglar redhanded. Then you say:

> I **had/have** a plan to be able to catch the burglar redhanded.

This is kinda confusing for me, it's like ''I wanted to go for a holiday'' to ''I want to go for a walk'' kind of thing... help, is it **had** or **have**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say

> I **have** a plan to be able to catch the burglar redhanded.

because you are talking about the present.
If you use "had", the sentence will become a past tense, which means that you had a plan in the past but now you don't have one.